# How can I use regex for testing id (in HTML) in Javascript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, onclick, dom-events

I'm pretty new here (in terms of asking qustions) and have encountered a problem where I cannot find any solutionon the internet.

I have got a Django template (the matter is not with Django) where I have

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="0">-- {% trans "Choisir" %} --</option>
    {% for site in sites %}
    <option value="{{ site.City }}" onclick='$("#{{site.City}}").show();'>{{ site.City }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

in order to show the div corresponding :`<div class="zone" id='{{site.City}}'>`
This works good and I can also show all div by clicking on the button :`<button class='small' onclick='$(".zone").show();'>{% trans "Show all" %}</button>`

What I want to do is having some other div **in** the site.City div like below :

```
{% for site in sites %}
    <div class="zone" id='{{site.City}}'>
        <h4>{% trans "Site" %} : {{ site.City }}</h4>
        {% for immo in immos %}
            {% if immo.idSite.City == site.City %}
                <div class='zone' id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}'>
```

I can show 1 div `id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}` with the onclick method using Javascript but I cannot find a way to show all div `id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}` in the div `id='{{site.City}}'` corresponding, without showing all div `id='{{site.City}}'`

I have searched some regex Javascript solution but it does not work.

```
onclick='$("#/^{{site.City}}/").show();'
```

It is like I want to test just on part of the id and using it in Javascript.
Is there a way of doing this? or what I am doing wrong?
The question is How can I use regex for testing id (in HTML) in Javascript `onclick` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In template:

```
{% for site in sites %}
    <div class="zone" id='{{site.City}}'>
        <h4>{% trans "Site" %} : {{ site.City }}</h4>
        {% for immo in immos %}
            {% if immo.idSite.City == site.City %}
                <div class='zone' id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}' class='city_{{site.City}}'>
```

click listener:

```
onclick='$(".city_{{site.City}}").show();'
```

[Jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (mostly) tries to be same as [CSS selectors](http://CSS%20selectors). CSS use classes when it required to select several items. Compare to ids: each node may have many classes and it's normal to have same class in different nodes.

Comment: But so the first class='zone' should be removed of course

Comment: I have adapted your answer but it works then thanks.